# Wicket 1.5 - timePicker lost after Target Ajax

Tags: ajax, wicket, timepicker

I have a TextField with "timePicker" as CSS class. Wicket change this input in a TimePicker (to select hour and minute).

This input is inside a WebMarkupContaner. After a specific Ajax event, the entire container is Targeted

```
target.add(container);
```

and so the input inside it. Unfortunally, the input lost the timePicker utility becoming a simple textfield.

I have tried, with Browser Javascript debug, to launch:

```
$("#inputId").timePicker();
```

and the input return to be a TimePicker. I deduce that Wicket attach the behavior only at the first page rendering.

How can I add the .timePicker() behavior after Ajax target?

Thanks

Comment: Please, post some time picker's initialization code and some code of AJAX event handler to clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try two things:

1) Add your JavaScript code to HTML markup of the container within <script /> tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#inputId").timePicker();
</script>
```

2) Append JavaScript to AJAX call for rendering the entire container:

```
target.add(container);
// append initialization JavaScript to AJAX call
target.appendJavascript("$(\"#inputId\").timePicker();");
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Reading the generated code, Wicket use this instruction: $(document).ready(function() etc... so, as deducted, it was launched only the first time.